# testng skipexception.isSkip method

Tags: java, testng

I am doing some queries in a data provider.  If the data queries do not return data I can use, rather than fail the test I would like to skip it.  So I
throw new SkipException( "Could not find adequate data" ) but this is failing the test rather than skipping it.

Some research shows that SkipException has a method isSkip() which will skip if true and fail if false. I dumped it before throwing the exception and it showed true, but the test is still failing.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to skip?  (yes I know you can put it in the @test() but I don't know how to do that after the test is running.

Comment: What is FQN of `SkipException`?

Answer (score 0):

If you throw a `SkipException` yes the test will fail. It's just like any other exception. If you want to skip a test you can do the following

1. Do @Test(enabled=false)
2. Implement [iAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) and then do a `annotation.setEnabled(false);`
   This will be a listener and you have to include that in your test or testng.xml or maven

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use SkipException in a data provider. Just send the result of the next query.